# Celery: can a task be created from inner function?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a celery task:

```
@task
def foo():
  part1()
  part2()
  part3()
```

...that I'm breaking up into a chain of subtasks

```
@task
def foo():
  @task
  def part1():
    ...

  @task
  def part2():
    ...

  @task
  def part3():
    ...

  chain(part1.s(), part2.s(), part3.s()).delay()
```

The subtasks are inner funcs because I don't want them executed outside the context of the parent task. Issue is my worker does not detect and/or register the inner tasks (I am using `autoregister` to discover apps and task modules). If I move them out to the same level in the module as the parent task `foo`, it works fine.

Does celery support inner functions as tasks? If so, how do I get workers to register them?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you get new definitions of `part1` every time you call `foo()`. Also note that not a single `part1` function is created until you call `foo` so it is not possible for celery to register any one of `part` functions to be created when it initializes a worker.

I think the following code is the closest to what you want.

```
def make_maintask():
    @task
    def subtask1():
        print("do subtask")

    # ...

    @task
    def _maintask():
        chain(subtask1.si(), subtask2.si(), subtask3.si()).delay()

    return _maintask


maintask = make_maintask()
```

This way, each definition of `subtask` and such is not visible from outside.

### some comments

- If all you want to do is hiding `subtask`, please think twice. The designer of the python language didn't believe that one needs a access control such as public and private as in java. It is a functionality that severely complicates a language with a dubious advantage. I think well-organized packages and modules and good names (such as adding underscores in front) can solve all your problems.
- If all `_maintask` does is delegating subtasks to other subprocesses, you don't really need to define it as a celery task. Don't make a celery task call another celery task unless you really need it.

Comment: I wasn't aware calling `delay()` within a task was not recommended. I assume it's necessary especially when using canvas which really has limited value within a task unless you call `delay()` on it. The docs aren't explicit about this client/worker distinction. Can you point me to a reference that says calling async tasks within tasks isn't recommended?

Comment: @Neil Sorry, I couldn't find some gentle introduction on that topic. [Introduction to Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) may help but I think the best way to learn this stuff is to play with it a bit. You can make your functions print some values and observe them.

Comment: I want to break my task up into subtasks that execute in parallel to avoid a single long running task. But I also don't want to expose all the logical pieces of a single task to the "client" and make them run them independently. So I assumed an acceptable pattern is to invoke async tasks from within other tasks

Comment: I've been working with Celery for a while and have always been following this approach of invoking async subtasks from within other async tasks. I have observed no behavior issues on Celery side doing this. That's why I was surprised by your comment and want to see if it's documented. There are many examples of this pattern in other SO questions, though the Celery docs don't seem explicit on this one way or the other

Comment: @Neil Well are you sure about using `chain` to parallelize your tasks? I don't think `chain` can do that..

Comment: @Neil Can you give me links to those questions having the pattern you mentioned? Maybe I can tell the differences once I have a look at them.

Comment: @Neil Making celery workers wait for another tasks(which can be considered as a IO bound operation) is a fundamentally bad idea. That can make the whole process idle.

I really recommend you to familiarize yourself with some important concepts for a remote procedure call, such as I/O bound and OS processes if you haven't studied them yet.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and questions!
Re: using chain, I understand it is serial rather than parallel and for certain use cases that's what I need. But in some cases we are ok with parallel. For e.g. in another task that has been running for years in our codebase, it calls `group(...).delay()`

Re: making celery workers wait, isn't calling `delay()` within a current task exactly the opposite? Part of why we call async tasks from within other tasks is to avoid making workers wait and tasks living a long time

Comment: FYI the docs do warn against launching sync subtasks:
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

If *async* subtasks were not recommended I would assume the above advice would have been totally different

Comment: @Neil Actually, the example supports my whole idea. Please observe that `update_page_info` is not defined as a celery task so it is not executed by workers (and it shouldn't be!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208493/discussion-between-neil-and-bombs).